# Get Access Token for Baidu Push Notification

Tags: android, push-notification, access-token, baidu

I am trying to get the access token for Baidu Push Notification. I've done everything according to their SDK documentation and I am able to send push notifications from their console. I went through their documentation and I am using this line of code to start the service.

```
PushManager.startWork(getApplicationContext(), PushConstants.LOGIN_TYPE_API_KEY, Utils.getMetaValue(SplashActivity.this, "api_key"));
```

there is **another method** that uses

```
 PushManager.startWork(getApplicationContext(), PushConstants.LOGIN_TYPE_ACCESS_TOKEN, Utils.getMetaValue(SplashActivity.this, "api_key"));
```

but I can't seem to get it to work or get the access token, probably due to a mistake in the code I am using. Could anyone guide me? I am able to get things like userId, channelId and requestId when I use the first method though, would one of these be the access token instead?

When I use the second method I get a "**30603   Illegal construction request, server-side validation failed**" error.

All of the guides are in Mandarin and Google Translate could only go so far. Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find your resultCode like this.

[your resultCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJuu0.png)

[code error list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7aFx.jpg)

Comment: I can see the results code, yes, but how am I to know which acts as an access token? Is it the channelId, userId or requestId?

Comment: There is no access token.You just only set the api_key right.

Comment: I set the API key and I can get notifications from console, but to send individual device notifications, you need the access token right? Isn't that what the below code is for:

**PushManager.startWork(getApplicationContext(), PushConstants.LOGIN_TYPE_ACCESS_TOKEN, Utils.getMetaValue(SplashActivity.this, "api_key"));**


Then what's the use of that piece of code? So you cannot get access tokens in Baidu Push?

Comment: I know that.The channelId is for send individual device notifications.

Comment: Will try individual push using channelId and accept answer if it is working.

Comment: Is channelId individual to device or user ? Because if I login with different user i am getting same channelId and userId

Comment: @Tyson Is channelId individual to device or user ? Because if I login with different user i am getting same channelId and userId

Comment: @Tyson Is channelId individual to device or user ? Because if I login with different user i am getting same channelId and userId